# How to switch new template edit mode from html to block view in new HubSpot beta Design Manager?

Tags: templates, hubspot

HubSpot released new *beta* Design Manager.

Do anyone knows how to switch new template edit mode from "html view" (this is my new template):

[image]

to "block view" (this is copy of existed template):

[image]

They are in different view...

Or maybe somebody knows, how to create new template in "block view"?

Is it possible in new *beta* version of HubSpot Design Manager?

I tried in different ways, but I can not find the view switch.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `HTML + HUBL` template, the one copied over from a template is a `Drag and drop` template. When you create a new file (right click on a folder -> `New file in "<dir>"`) you can select which one you'd like.

As far as I know you can't switch from a html template to a drag and drop template (you can however clone a drag and drop template to a file).

But hey; if you can write html and css, don't use the drag and drop builder. It might look easy, but it gets you in all sorts of trouble when trying to customize.